# Accessing Data retrieved using Fuel SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

I'm creating a lightweight opt-out/profile center using the the Fuel SDK. My method is to use the email address a person inputs to retrieve the subscriber's ID. This ID will then be used to either update their profile with a new email address or unsubscribe them based on their selections in the form.

The problem is that when I retrieve a subscriber using the retrieve code for Fuel, I can't seem to assign the pertinent data to an actual variable. For instance:

```
$subscriber = new ET_Subscriber(); //Retrieve
$subscriber->authStub = $myclient;
$subscriber->props = array('EmailAddress', 'ID');
$subscriber->filter = array('Property' => 'EmailAddress','SimpleOperator' =>  'equals','Value' => example@example.com);
$response = $subscriber->get();
```

The code above will retrieve the subscriber info for the subscriber with example@exmaple.com as their email. But what I need to do is assign the ID number of this selected subscriber to a variable. But the object type in $response is ET_Get which tells me it cannot be treated as an array. So how does one go about actually accessing the data so that I can make this pseudo code work:

```
$idNumber = $response->ID;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you do a

```
print_r($response);
```

You'll see that there is a attribute "responses", each of which contains an ID

Ie. $response->responses[0]->ID

You have to check
- $response->responses is not empty
- $response->responses may be more than one. The same email address can be stored under different subscriber ids